# Recognize Shuffled dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification, weka

I have two datasets, one of them is the real dataset and one of them is a randomized dataset
where the class attribute has been randomly shuffled. How can I determine which is
which? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Train a classifier. The data set where you can get a working classifier is probably the one with the real labels. On the shuffled one, no classifier should work!

There is no guarantee you can detect it. If your data was random before, it doesn't get more random by shuffling; so you cannot decide then. But if the data set had a nice structure before, then shuffling should usually destroy this.

Comment: That is correct. I used WEKA and tree classifier, and results confirm what you mentioned. Thank you Anony.